# Mybatis upgrade issues related to parameters

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-generator

I was trying to upgrade my spring version from 4 to 5.3.23
Also updated Jackson databind to 2.13.5
While doing so I needed to upgrade mybatis from 3.0 to 3.5.11
Also mybatis-spring from 1.0 to 2.1.0

While upgrading, i found strange behaviour happening to mybatis requests.

I’m getting an error -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property '__frch_token_1'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType

(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode): jdbcType (null) combination. ### Cause:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property __frch_token_1'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType

(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode):

jdbcType (null) combination.
```

With earlier version of mybatis, it was working fine.

I’m passing multiple or single parameter from drop down from front end on iName column

It’s breaking at for each loop, it seems.

```
<select id="getByCriteria" resultMap="xyzResultMap">

<![CDATA[SELECT ]]>

<include refid="columns" />

<![CDATA[ FROM Table ]]> != null">

<if test="criteria <where>

<foreach collection "criteria" item="item" separator="AND">
 <!-- column name -->

<choose>

<when test=‘“Id".equals (item.fieldName)’>Eid</when> 
<when test=‘"Name".equals(item.fieldName)’> iName</when> 


<otherwise>/* unknown field name ${item.fieldName} */</otherwise>

</choose> 
<!-- operator and search value -->

<choose>

<when test=’"equals".equals(item.operator)'>= #{item.value}</when>

<when test=’"iCaptains".equals(item.operator)'> like UPPER('%${item.value}%')</wh

<when test=’"inSet".equals(item. operator)'><![CDATA[ IN (]]>

<foreach collection="item.value" item- "token" separator=", ">

<![CDATA[ #{token}]]>

</foreach><![CDATA[)]]>

/when>

<otherwise>/* unknown field name ${item.operator} */</otherwise>

</choose> </foreach>

</where>
</if>
```

Can somebody give me insights about this issue .

After implementing arraynodetype handler I was able to remove that error but I’m not getting correct results.

Seems like prepared statement is not generated correctly.

[image]

Comment: Was this `when tesst=‘“IId"` a typo ?

Comment: Yea ignore this, it’s a typo. Everything worked if I downgrade mybatis to 3.0

Comment: By the looks of the error alone it looks like there is an issue with the type handler used for a parameter mapping in your MyBatis configuration that was either default on the previous version and needs to be explicit on the newer (mainly because you updated Jackson? Not entirely sure about this), so try configuring a type handler for it it is something like: `<typeHandlers><typeHandler javaType="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode" handler="what.ever.package.ArrayNodeHandler"/></typeHandlers>"` or whatever version of this for the new Jackson.

Comment: Also check that the version you are using for myBatis is compatible with the version you are using for Jackson library. It might be another source of the problem

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCampos for looking into this. However I’m unable to find any  ArrayNodeHandler implementation. I’m also unsure about it, I doubt if it really exists?

Comment: Hmm that might be the problem them. can you check whether the previous version of jackson or mybatis has it ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos   However I tried to create new type handler for jsonArrayNode.    Like mentioned on post- but this time I’m not getting any error but I’m getting wrong results. Seems like it’s is not generating correct prepared statement

Comment: @Inked The XML syntax is clearly invalid. It's hard to help without accurate info, but it seems that the element type of the collection `item.value` was changed during the upgrade (possibly because of some change made in Jackson?). If you could provide a test case that reproduces the same issue (i.e. the test passes with version 3.0.x, but fails with 3.5.11), I would take a look when I have time. Here are some project [templates and examples](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues). Please try to make the project as simple as possible.